# java:variable initialisation

Tags: java, variables

i'm trying to create a class that contains functions that login and logout from the server, the ip address of the server is defined in a static way in the beginning of the function, like this:

```
private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.1.5/android_login_api/"
```

I would like to know the best to initialize the loginURL dependending of a condition.
For example:

```
if(this.isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.5", 500)) {
    private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.1.5/android_login_api/";
}

if(this.isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.9", 500)) {
    private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.1.9/android_login_api/";
}
```

I thought of passing the loginURL as a parameter to every function of this class then when i call them i use this condition to define the ip address but i think it's too silly.

here is my class:

```
public class UserFunctions {

private JSONParser jsonParser;

private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.1.5/android_login_api/";
private static String mplayerURL = "http://192.168.1.5/android_mplayer_api/";
private static String registerURL = "http://192.168.1.5/android_login_api/";

private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";
private static String delete_tag = "delete";
private static String update_tag = "update";
private static String music_tag = "music";
private static String getusers_tag = "getusers";


// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject loginUser(String email, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", login_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}
public JSONObject deleteUser(String email){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", delete_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}

public JSONObject updateUser(String email, String field, String value){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", update_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("field", field));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("value", value));
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(loginURL, params);
    // return json
    Log.i("JSON", json.toString());
    return json;
}



public boolean isConnectedToServer(String url, int timeout) {
    try{
        URL myUrl = new URL(url);
        URLConnection connection = myUrl.openConnection();
        connection.setConnectTimeout(timeout);
        connection.connect();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle your exceptions
        return false;
    }
}

/**
 * function make Login Request
 * @param name
 * @param email
 * @param password
 * */
public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String mode, String password){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mode", mode));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(registerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

    public JSONObject PlayMusic(String name){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "play"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(mplayerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

public JSONObject ChangeVol(String volume){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "volume"));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("volume", volume));
    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(mplayerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}

public JSONObject StopMusic(){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "stop"));
    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(mplayerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}


public JSONObject ParcourirMusic(){
    // Building Parameters
    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", "parcourir"));
    // getting JSON Object
    JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(mplayerURL, params);
    // return json
    return json;
}


/**
 * Function get Login status
 * */
public boolean isUserLoggedIn(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    int count = db.getRowCount();
    if(count > 0){
        // user logged in
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * Function to logout user
 * Reset Database
 * */
public boolean logoutUser(Context context){
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
    db.resetTables();
    return true;
}

public void ReadMail(){

try{
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "rami.mtiri@gmail.com", "pass");
Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);


SearchTerm term = new SearchTerm() {
  @Override
  public boolean match(Message mess) {
    try {
      return mess.getContent().toString().toLowerCase().indexOf("boston") != -1;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
     // Logger.getLogger(JavaMailTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (MessagingException ex) {
     // Logger.getLogger(JavaMailTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return false;
  }
};

Message[] searchResults = inbox.search(term);
for(Message m:searchResults){
    Log.e("mail",m.getFrom()[0].toString() );
  System.out.println("MATCHED: " + m.getFrom()[0]);

}
} catch (Exception e) {

}

}

}
```

please can anyone give me a full solution using my code UP, i'm new in java dont care if the the function or the variavble is static or not , all i want is to initalize the ip address by condition. i call the functions of this class in evry other class so it will be rude to do tests in evry class. im keeping that as a last resort

Comment: send the IP address alone from the calling method and append the rest of the static string to it. No need for any checks as such.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - you're updating a static string based on the results of an instance method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
if(this.isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.5", 500))
{
    private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.1.5/android_login_api/";
}
if(this.isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.9", 500))
{
    private static String loginURL = "http://192.168.1.9/android_login_api/";
}
```

Is not valid java code, assuming that the above statements lie within the declaration of a class (the usage of the `private static` modifiers require this to be the case).

Fields cannot be conditionally declared. If fact, most statements (if, while, for, so on) are illegal outside of functions. The only thing you can do statically within the class body is to declare the field and give it an initialization value.

```
private static String loginURL; //no initialization yet as you don't have an instance to call isConnectedToServer() on
```

Now, it is very difficult to solve your problem because as Adrian pointed out, you are trying to use a non-static method (`isConnectedToServer()`) to determine static behavior (the value of `loginURL`). This doesn't make sense. You must either you make `loginURL` non-static or make `isConnectedToServer()` static.

You probably want the first the first option.

Due to the nature of your initialization conditions it would easier to initialize `loginURL` in a a constructor, which would be almost exactly the same as initializing it statically. Here would be a skeleton example of such a setup:

```
class Example
{
     private String loginURL; //non-static, no initialization

     public Example()//construcutor
     {
           //run conditions normally
           if(this.isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.5", 500))
           {
                loginURL = "http://192.168.1.5/android_login_api/";
           }
           //you might want to use else if here
           if(this.isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.9", 500))
           {
                loginURL = "http://192.168.1.9/android_login_api/";
           }
           //if neither if starement executes, loginURL is null.
     }
}
```

If you *do* want the functionality to be static for whatever reason, move the initialization code to a static block:

```
class StaticExample
{
     private static String loginURL;

     //isConnectedToServer must be declared static in order for this to work!
     //I believe your current function can be made static without changing its code
     public static boolean isConnectedToServer()
     {
        ...
     }

     static
     {
           if(isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.5", 500))
           {
                loginURL = "http://192.168.1.5/android_login_api/";
           }
           //you might want to use else if here
           if(isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.9", 500))
           {
                loginURL = "http://192.168.1.9/android_login_api/";
           }
           //if neither if starement executes, loginURL is null.
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

all i had to do is to initialize the var in the constructor this way:

```
private JSONParser jsonParser;

private static String loginURL = "/android_login_api/";
private static String mplayerURL = "/android_mplayer_api/";
private static String registerURL = "/android_login_api/";
public String ip;
private static String login_tag = "login";
private static String register_tag = "register";
private static String delete_tag = "delete";
private static String update_tag = "update";
private static String music_tag = "music";
private static String getusers_tag = "getusers";


// constructor
public UserFunctions(){
    jsonParser = new JSONParser();
    if(isConnectedToServer("192.168.1.5", 500)==false)
    {
        if(isConnectedToServer("www.google.com", 500)==true)
        {
            ReadEmails re = new ReadEmails();
            ip=re.processMail();
        }else{
            ip="192.168.1.5";
        }
    }else{
        ip="192.168.1.5";
    }
}
```